# SSIS tool box menu is visible but on clicking it is not opening in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

SSIS tool box menu is Visible [image]
but on clicking nothing happens.
I am setting up a new project using `Integration Service (BI)`. when I right click from `Control flow` tab I am able to see `SSIS` Toolbox menu but when I click on it nothing happens. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Doesn't it show up att all?

Comment: I am able to see the menu option but nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing SSIS toolbox in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102365/missing-ssis-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Have you Ever Used it or the first time ?

Comment: No I have used it before everything else is working I am able to see my previous project only issue is that tool box is not opening on clicking.

Comment: Actually SSIS tool box menu is visible but on clicking its not opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I have installed VS 2017 15.9.5 and its SSDT 15.8.0 from

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

In this version I am not facing any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I have this error I click here and it shows up.

[image: SSIS toolbox icon]

Comment: What if you go to VIEW -> Other Windows -> SSIS Toolbox ?. Can you post a screenshot ?

Comment: Actually I have tried that too. Currently I have installed VS 2017 and its SSDT  there its working correctly, but still same issue exists in VS 2015