# Why is my SSIS toolbox empty in Visual Studio 2019 community?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, toolbox, ssis-2019

I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community and then installed data tools. I can open an Integration Services project but when I look at the SSIS Tooolbox, it's empty.

How do I fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Mike Aono's answer is the quick simple fix with VS 2019

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a problem after Visual Studio does an update for Optimization.

I have confirmed that the fix is:

Open menu item:
 - Tools
  - Options
    - Environment - On the General Tab - DISABLE/uncheck - "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities"

This solved my problem.

..Derrick..

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  And I do have the Extension installed @Hadi but I was hoping you were right.  I turned it back On after they showed up with the flag Off, but they disappeared again.  The flag must be Off for the tools to show up.

Comment: Here's the developer community ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/663977/ssis-toolbox-in-visual-studio-19-empty.html

Comment: Same applies for Visual Studio Professional 2019 v. 16.3.1 using framework 4.8.03752. I installed the separate SSDT package and the above behavior was demonstrated, this fix solved my issue.

Comment: Excellent find!  I just spent some time reinstalling a new machine and I hit this issue.  Saves me from throwing my box out of a window

Comment: This is an extremely unfortunate state of affairs

Comment: problems back in 16.11.1, above fix doesn't work, but in settings xaml designer has to be enabled.

Comment: I had to restart VS but it worked after restart. Thanks!

Answer (score 59):

I am using visual studio 2017, To get the SSIS toolbox back, right-click on the SSIS design surface in the project and select SSIS Toolbox please see [this link](https://iaincarlin.com/ylsned/ssis-toolbox-missing-in-visual-studio-2017/). This resolved it for me.

Adding the content below again, in case the webpage is not available in future.

> I have installed the Data-Tier Application Framework and SQL Server
> Data Tools for VS 2017 . I created a solution then returned to it a
> week later and the SSIS toolbox had disappeared.
>
> I opened the toolbox window using View -> Toolbox but it was empty.
>
> To get the SSIS toolbox back, right-click on the SSIS design surface
> in the project and select SSIS Toolbox – hey presto! it reappears.

Comment: Yes. You should be the correct answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe the correct answer worked for some people, but this answer worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Solved my problem.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2019 as well and I got the SSIS toolbox back. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This has been an issue for many version, but hasn't happened to me in a while and I couldn't remember how to fix. Thanks for posting. It's just another annoying VS SSIS bug in the very long and never ending list of SSIS VS bugs that MS seems determined to never fix.

Answer (score 22):

A Picture is worth of thousand words

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download and install the Integration Services Projects extension:

- [SQL Server Integration Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

Since in Visual Studio 2019, for Analysis Services, Integration Services or Reporting Services projects, you have to install the appropriate extension(s) from the marketplace.

You can refer to the following official documentation for additional information:

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Additionally, the extension can be searched within VS itself, through Tools > Extensions and Updates and search for Integration services and Install the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project from 2017 and the toolbar would not open when I opened the project. I had to create a new empty project. Then go back and open the 2017 project. Then the toolbar appeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me, enabling SSIS toolbox did the trick initially it did not show up in VS 2019 community

Steps :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48102622/2256502

Answer (score -1):

My two cents worth, I had the same issue-

In the toolbox window, right-click and select SHOW ALL.
Then right-click again, and turn off the SHOW ALL. Voilah...!

Comment: Show All will show all tools even those that cannot be used for SSIS. 
All of them are disabled.