# Unable to view ssis toolbox

Tags: ssis

I installed 2022 visual studio, but I'm unable to see the ssis tool box - I have looked in view-> and there is nothing there and also in the other windows but it doesn't seem to exist.

Would you please let me know where or how it can be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing SSIS toolbox in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102365/missing-ssis-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: To fix the issue, the following steps were taken: after opening Visual Studio, select ‘continues without code’ link -> on the top menu select Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> on the left hand side of the screen, select ‘Online’ then select Visual Studio market please -> download the integration services and install.